Substrate: How to call / import functions in the same pallet
Folders and file inside my pallet:
rpc, runtime-api, src, tests, Cargo.toml

Inside src/abc.rs:
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
    #[allow(clippy::indexing_slicing)]
    pub fn doAction(id: u16, bool_opt: Option<bool>) -> Vec<(u64, u64)> {
        let my_value: u64 = get_my_value(netuid);
    }
}

How can I call one function from src/utils?
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
    pub fn get_my_value(id: u16) -> u64 {
        MyValues::<T>::get(id)
    }
}

I tried adding use crate::utils::*; in my abc.rs, but it does not work.

There is nothing specific happening here specific to Polakdot SDK or Pallets.
For a more rustic answer:
You have a struct Pallet.
You are implementing functions on the Pallet struct:
// Removing the generic stuff to make the example easy to understand.
pub struct Pallet;

// Implementing functions on the `Pallet` struct.
impl Pallet {
    fn one() -> u32 {
        1u32
    }

    pub fn two() -> u32 {
        2u32
    }
}

// You can make as many `impl Pallet` blocks as you want.
impl Pallet {
    fn three() -> u32 {
        3u32
    }

    // Inside any `impl Pallet`, you can access any other
    // function implemented on `Pallet` by referring to `Self`.
    fn add_one_two_three() -> u32 {
        Self::one() + Self::two() + Self::three()
    }
}

If you are outside the impl Pallet, you can access any pub functions by referencing the struct the function is implemented on:
// We assume the `Pallet` struct is in scope.
fn my_external_function() -> u32 {
    Pallet::two()
    // You cannot access `one()` or `three()` because they are not `pub`
} 


Thank you for the detailed explanation :)

To use functions in the same pallet:
let out = Self::get_my_value(id);

